# How does the ng_copy work actually in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs-directive

How does the `ng-copy` work actually?

I came across the below code and unable to connect the working of `ng-copy`

```
<input ng-copy="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" value="Copy this text" />
<p>The text has been copied {{count}} times.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me in Chrome 70 on a Mac. [Here's a stackblitz showing it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-zevncx?file=home%2Fhome.html).

[image]

Are you using a browser that supports the `copy` event? Note that [it's not universally supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).